# How to stop the value from becoming zero in every function call in the following code?

Tags: c, logic

I am trying to write a code to solve the problem of taking two numbers m and n as an input from user and then calculating A(m,n) as follows:

```
            1.  A(m,n) = A(m,n-1) + A(m-1,n) , m,n >=0 

            2.  A(m,n) = m-n if m<0 or n<0
```

I have written the following code in C, but the problem is that the answer coming is not correct, because the initialization of the variable value to zero, erases the value while recursion is going on and the answer I get is incorrect. Anybody knows how to solve this issue?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int num1=0;
    int num2=0;
    int rows=0;
    int columns=0;
    int i,j,**array;
    printf("Enter two non-negative integer numbers \n");
    scanf("%d %d",&num1,&num2);  

    //create 2d-Array

    rows=num1+1;
    columns=num2+1;
    array=malloc(rows * sizeof(int *));

    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
       array[i]=malloc(columns*sizeof(int));    
    }

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
      for(j= 0; j < columns; j++ )
      {
          array[i][j]=0;
      }
    } 

    //Fill data in array

    computeArray(array,rows,columns);


    // Display contents of array
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
      for(j= 0; j < columns; j++ )
      {
         printf("array[%d][%d] = %d\n", i,j, array[i][j] );
      }
    }    

    getch();
    return 0;
}

int computeArray (int **array, int rows, int columns)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<rows;i++)
    {
            for(j=0;j<columns;j++)
            {
                 array[i][j]=computeFunction(array,i,j);
            }
    }        
    return **array;
}

int computeFunction(int **array, int i, int j)
{
    printf("Value reset by zero\n");
    int value=0;
    if((i<0)||(j <0))
    {
        value = i-j; 
        printf("Value contains i-j value\n");
        return value;                 
    }         
    else
    {
        value = (computeFunction(array,i,j-1)+ computeFunction(array,i-1,j));
        printf("Value updated after else\n");
        return value;
    }
}
```

The answer for 0,0 should be -2, but I am getting 0 due to the initialization issue. Please let me know if you know how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Which initialization issue do you mean? The recursive function looks correct. (You don't need to initialize `value` to zero, but if you do it doesn't hurt.)

Comment: @Inspired I am initializing variable value to zero, otherwise output contains garbage values.

Comment: According to the formula you gave, the value for 0,0 should not be -2 but 0.  Is there any other behavior that makes you think the program is incorrect?

Comment: @user3097157 No, there is no garbage if you remove `=0` for `value`. And there cannot be any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's being computed correctly - it should be 0.

> 1. A(m,n) = A(m,n-1) + A(m-1,n) , m,n >=0
> 2. A(m,n) = m-n if m<0 or n<0

So `A(0,0) = A(0,-1) + A(-1,0) = (0 - (-1)) + (-1 - 0) = 1 + (-1) = 0`

Comment: Yep, you are correct. I guess I need some coffee :) Thanks btw